# change server name returned to application using nginx config?

Tags: nginx, flask, http-headers

**Short Version:**

Is it possible to make nginx change server name "myexample.com" to "example.com" and return that to applications using it?Application is using uwsgi_pass in server tag of nginx.

**Long Version:**

I have an nginx server that runs a Flask application. it uses uwsgi_pass and a socket to run the application.
My Flask application has

```
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'example.com'
```

to resolve sub-domains (I have few blueprints to work on subdomains). I also registered another sub-domain such as myexample.com which I want to redirect to this server IP and act exactly the same.
But I know because flask uses that "example.com" for subdomain resolution, it wont work!

I could not a find to do it in flask, but I was wondering is it possible to make nginx for "myexample.com" change server name to "example.com" then pass it to application?I think this way it should work fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible as Nginx supports regex.

Not sure about Flask, but, for example, on PHP:

```
server
{
    server_name           ~^(?<project>.+)\.dev$;
    set $root /var/www/$project;
    root $root;
    error_log             /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE $project;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
        include       /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  development;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    }
}
```

PHP will have a variable called `$MAGE_RUN_CODE` with the value of `$project` with matches the regex.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
  proxy_set_header   HOST     "example.com" ;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/;
  proxy_buffering off;
```